# Reloading UITableView from a button in another class (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have an application where I am trying to implement an add to cart function in a multi-tab application. I have one tab for my shop page and one tab for my cart page, and I've set up my shop page to be a table view where each cell leads to a view controller with the information of the product where inside you can click an add to cart button that adds the product to an array that is later displayed in my cart page's tableview.

The issue I'm having is that, once I navigate to the cart page and I try to add items to the cart, the array changes (tested it through prints), but the tableView doesn't reload and I don't see the items being added. If I just go to the shop page and then add items and then open the cart, all the items load, but I can't add anymore.

How do I make it so when I click the add to cart button (in another class and another view), it refreshes the tableView (in the other class) and updates, even after my tableView has already initially loaded?

Here is my code for the button (the commented spot says where I want some sort of function to reload the table):

```
@IBAction func addToCartPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    //Code that adds the item to the array called cartArray that is in the other class
    // I want to call a "table reload" here so that it reloads the tableView on the cart page

    viewDidLoad()
    }
```

And here is my viewController for the cart page:

```
import UIKit
var cartArray =  [Cart(name: "initial", thumbnails: "sgA1.jpg", price: "initial", quantity: 0)]
class CartViewController: UIViewController{

@IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tableView.dataSource = self
    tableView.reloadData()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}}

extension CartViewController: UITableViewDataSource{
     func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if(cartArray[0].name.isEqual("initial")){
            return 0
        }
        else{
        return cartArray.count
        }
    }

     func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as? CartViewCell {
            cell.configurateTheCell(cartArray[indexPath.row])
            return cell
        }
        tableView.reloadData()
        return UITableViewCell()
        
    }
}
```

I want to be able to reload the tableView here somehow after I've updated the array through my click of the button in the other class. How do I do it?

Comment: Dont declare your array as a global variable. make it a property of your view controller. if you need to change its value in another controller you can make the other controller the delegate of the tableview controller. You can also pass the controller instance object to the other view controller and update the array property and/or reload the tableview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reload the table view every time your `cartArray` updates.

Simply do the following

```
var cartArray =  [Cart(name: "initial", thumbnails: "sgA1.jpg", price: "initial", quantity: 0)] {
    didSet { 
       NotificationCenter
           .default
           .post(Notification(name: "cartArrayUpdated"))
    }
}
```

Then add your `CartViewController` as observer for that notification

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tableView.dataSource = self
    tableView.reloadData()
    NotificationCenter
       .default
       .addObserver(self, 
                    selector: #selector(refresh), 
                    name: .init("cartArrayUpdated"), 
                    object: nil)
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
```

Then inside `CartViewController` just create the function that handles your tableview refresh

```
@objc func refresh() {
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Also don't forget to remove `CartViewController` as observer when is no longer needed. After `viewDidLoad` add the following

```
deinit {
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
}
```

Also I agree with @Leo Dabus declaring this array as global variable is a bad practice. You should have this inside `CartViewController` then all you had to do is just

```
var cartArray =  [Cart(name: "initial", thumbnails: "sgA1.jpg", price: "initial", quantity: 0)] {
    didSet { 
       tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Comment: I made the cartArray outside the class in order to access it in otherclases, so it says tableView is an unresolved identifier. How do I fix this? I also tried using a protocol, but am not sure exactly how to use it. If you could give me some code to follow in order to implement it that would be great.